# Reversing a CSS3 animation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

According to a book, the example below should fade-in and -out the menu, but Instead the menu disappears immediately. I believe the problem is that `display: none` take effect too early somehow, but I am not sure since it says `display: block` in the animation.

What can I do to make the grey div fade out smooth instead of just disappearing? A solution only using CSS for the animation would be preferred.

CSS

```
a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.bar {
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
}

.div {
    background: silver;
    padding: 10px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
    -webkit-animation: fade 2s reverse;
    animation: fade 2s reverse;
}

.shown {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation: fade 2s;
    animation: fade 2s;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="bar">
    <a href="#" class="click">Click Me</a>
    <div class="div shown">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $div = $(".div");

    var menu = function () {
        if ( $div.hasClass("shown")) {
            $div.removeClass("shown");
            $div.addClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $div.removeClass("hidden");
            $div.addClass("shown");
        }

    }

    menu();

    $(".click").bind("click", menu);

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hFdbt/1/

Comment: keyframes is only supported from ie10 and on. I see no reason not to do it with javascript only. You rely on javascript for the click event anyways, so you gain nothing from using css animations.

Comment: you need to change display:none to opacity:0 [http://jsfiddle.net/hFdbt/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/hFdbt/5/)

Comment: Setting the display property to 'none' will terminate any running animation applied to the element and its descendants

Comment: You can leave display: block always. Then add/remove a class with opacity: 0; (you don't need 2 classes for that). And last, you can use just a transition instead of an animation (much easier).

Answer (score 2):

As i said in my comment, you might just aswell use jquery for it.

jQuery

```
$(".click").on("click", function() {
    $(".div").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="bar">
    <a href="#" class="click">Click Me</a>
    <div class="div shown">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.bar {
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
}

.div {
    background: silver;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QvpS3/

Comment: I don't know. It looks correct to me. Somebody might have down voted you because he said CSS3 Animations preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not transition on the display element (think of it as a boolean or enum, there is nothing but "true" and "false", as in there is no true.5 ), you must use some other method to hide the element.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3n1gm4/Q5TBN/) (http://jsfiddle.net/3n1gm4/Q5TBN/) I've used the `max-height` property and `overflow: hidden` along with `transition` to set the delay.

```
.hidden {
    -webkit-animation: fade 2s reverse;
    animation: fade 2s reverse;

    -webkit-transition: 0s all 2s; /* delay this the duration of the animation */
    transition-delay: 0s all 2s;
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0;

    overflow: hidden;

}

.shown {
    -webkit-animation: fade 2s;
    animation: fade 2s;
    max-height: 5000px; /* some number way bigger than it will ever be to avoid clipping */
}
```

credits: [Transitions on the display: property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)